# What is the correct notation for binary digital image and dice score?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, image-processing

I wanted to ensure the correctness of notation regarding some concepts of digital images. If I have a binary image $X$ of width $W$ and height $H$ is the correct notation for describing image $X$:
$$X \in \{0, 1\}^{W\text{x}H}$$

Also, I have seen the definition of the [Dice Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) using the set notation for binary images but I still cant find the sense of it using `sets`:

$$\frac{2 \mid X \cap Y \mid}{\mid X \mid + 
\mid Y \mid}$$

Since $\mid X \mid$ and $\mid Y \mid$ express the cardinality, as I understand, these will be the total number of pixels and not the non-zero pixels. Note: The other definition posted in the link makes absolute sense; I just want to understand if the set definition can also, in some way, be extended for images.

Comment: You should ask each question separately.  I am not sure what the intersection of two images is.  I suppose if they were strictly black/white you could count the pixels where the colors match.  With any other color scheme you need to define how close is close enough or the intersection will be very small

Comment: Yes, as the question says, they are `binary` images. The problem is how the set definition applies to images. On the link I posted, they define the dice score using matrix operations, which is straightforward to understand. Since I have seen the set definition on multiple image processing papers, I want to know how it applies.

Comment: I would assume you just count the pixels that agree, those that are black in both images and those that are white in both

Comment: Yes, in fact you only count the non-zero ones that agree. My question is more of how to represent the image as a set so the definition applies.

Comment: The image can just be the set of black pixels.  You probably then want to take the intersection of $X$ and $Y$ and count the pixels in that, then add the size of the intersection of $X^c$ and $Y^c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single correct notation. Often images are defined as a function on a discrete domain $D \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.

But when talking about binary images as sets, only the true (foreground) pixels are considered part of the set. So the cardinality of the binary image set is the number of true (foreground) pixels. This explains the Dice score definition.